# Convert xml to xlsx vbscript

Tags: vbscript, adsutil.vbs

I have a vbscript code, where I convert from xml to xlsx. However, when converting it duplicates the information and takes the order of the columns. How do I reverse or adjust? Because I'm not able to format correctly. If you use excel and open it by hand and convert to xlsx it is correct.

This is my vbs code:

```
Dim xlApp, xlWkb, SourceFolder, TargetFolder, file
Set xlApp = CreateObject ("excel.application")
Set fs = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForWriting = 2
Const TristateTrue = -1
Const xlNormal = 51

SourceFolder = "C: \ Users \ Convex \ Documents \ MICHAEL \ XML"
TargetFolder = "C: \ Users \ Convex \ Documents \ MICHAEL \ XLS"
xlApp.Visible = false

for each file in fs.GetFolder (SourceFolder) .files
  Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open (file)
  BaseName = fs.getbasename (file)
  FullTargetPath = TargetFolder & "\" & BaseName & ".xlsx"
  xlWkb.SaveAs FullTargetPath, xlNormal
  xlWkb.close
next
'Uncomment this line to delete the source file
'fs.DeleteFile ("C: \ xml-to-xls \ xml \ *. xml")
Set xlWkb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

This is the xml:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<Transaction>
  <list>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 5 </matricula>
      <name> ANGEL EDUARDO TRIGUEROS CISNEROS </name>
      <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 9 </matricula>
      <name> MARCO AURELIO CARNEIRO </name>
      <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 6 </matricula>
      <name> ADRIELLE ROSA CAMARGO DE ANDRADE </name>
      <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 3 </matricula>
      <name> GUILHERME QUINTINO RIBEIRO </name>
      <cpf> 0000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 14 </matricula>
      <name> TIAGO DA FONTE LEITE </name>
      <cpf> 00000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 2 </matricula>
      <name> LUIZ ANTONIO SACCO </name>
      <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 10 </matricula>
      <name> JULIANA PEREIRA DA CUNHA WALENKAMP </name>
      <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 8 </matricula>
      <name> MARCEL KEITI TOMA </name>
      <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 13 </matricula>
      <name> CRISTIANE BONATES MACEDO DE AMO </name>
      <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 11 </matricula>
      <name> LUIS ANTONIO PAIN JUNIOR </name>
      <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 12 </matricula>
      <name> FLAVIO DALE LUCHE </name>
      <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 1 </matricula>
      <name> BRUNO VIEIRA ROBERTI </name>
      <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 4 </matricula>
      <name> GUILHERME GAMEIRO DUARTE </name>
      <cpf> 00000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
    <registers>
      <matricula> 7 </matricula>
      <name> CARLA FERNANDA PASQUALI </name>
      <cpf> 0000000 </cpf>
    </registrates>
  </list>
</Transaction>
    
    This is my vbs code:
    Dim xlApp, xlWkb, SourceFolder, TargetFolder, file
    Set xlApp = CreateObject ("excel.application")
    Set fs = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Const ForWriting = 2`enter code here`
    Const TristateTrue = -1
    Const xlNormal = 51
    
    SourceFolder = "C: \ Users \ Convex \ Documents \ MICHAEL \ XML"
    TargetFolder = "C: \ Users \ Convex \ Documents \ MICHAEL \ XLS"
    xlApp.Visible = false
    
    for each file in fs.GetFolder (SourceFolder) .files
      Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open (file)
      BaseName = fs.getbasename (file)
      FullTargetPath = TargetFolder & "\" & BaseName & ".xlsx"
      xlWkb.SaveAs FullTargetPath, xlNormal
      xlWkb.close
    next
    'Uncomment this line to delete the source file
    'fs.DeleteFile ("C: \ xml-to-xls \ xml \ *. xml")
    Set xlWkb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    
    
    This is the xml:
    <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <Transaction>
      <list>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 5 </matricula>
          <name> ANGEL EDUARDO TRIGUEROS CISNEROS </name>
          <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 9 </matricula>
          <name> MARCO AURELIO CARNEIRO </name>
          <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 6 </matricula>
          <name> ADRIELLE ROSA CAMARGO DE ANDRADE </name>
          <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 3 </matricula>
          <name> GUILHERME QUINTINO RIBEIRO </name>
          <cpf> 0000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 14 </matricula>
          <name> TIAGO DA FONTE LEITE </name>
          <cpf> 00000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 2 </matricula>
          <name> LUIZ ANTONIO SACCO </name>
          <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 10 </matricula>
          <name> JULIANA PEREIRA DA CUNHA WALENKAMP </name>
          <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 8 </matricula>
          <name> MARCEL KEITI TOMA </name>
          <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 13 </matricula>
          <name> CRISTIANE BONATES MACEDO DE AMO </name>
          <cpf> 00000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 11 </matricula>
          <name> LUIS ANTONIO PAIN JUNIOR </name>
          <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 12 </matricula>
          <name> FLAVIO DALE LUCHE </name>
          <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 1 </matricula>
          <name> BRUNO VIEIRA ROBERTI </name>
          <cpf> 000000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 4 </matricula>
          <name> GUILHERME GAMEIRO DUARTE </name>
          <cpf> 00000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
        <registers>
          <matricula> 7 </matricula>
          <name> CARLA FERNANDA PASQUALI </name>
          <cpf> 0000000 </cpf>
        </registrates>
      </list>
    </Transaction>
```

Comment: The  <registers> node is closed as  </registrates>. You might need to correct that

Comment: **it duplicates the information and takes the order of the columns** What does that mean? Can you show the problem?

Comment: Geert Bellekens: When converting the xml to the xlsx format it duplicates the data and messes up the order of the data. Example: registration register, in the conversion to xlsx it goes to the name column. The record name goes to the cpf column. etc...